# spring data exists by all values of some column

Tags: spring, spring-data, hql

I want to know, is there set of entities by following rule:

I have a table with two primary keys:

```
| id | key |
| 1  | a   |
| 2  | b   |
| 1  | c   |
```

So, I want to do something like that:

```
boolean existsByIdAndAllOfKey(
  long id,
  Set<Key> keys
)
```

This query should return true if in the database there are entities with all keys presented in input Set.

I wondering is there any keyword from spring data? Or what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

found following solution:

```
    int countByIdAndKeyIn(
      long id,
      Set<Key> keys
    )

boolean isThereEntityWithAllKeys(long id, Set<Key> keys) {
   return countByIdAndKeyIn(id, keys) == keys.size;
}
```